# Get a file path as an argument in the global node package

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to create a global node package for doing something in the running directory of that package.
For example, I want to remove some files with that node package CLI. The command will be something like this:

```sh
my-package ./test-file.txt
```

How can I get the `./test-file.txt` path as an argument in the package node app?
I think it should be in the argument but if there is a better way I will appreciate knowing that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful information. How can I get the full path of that file? the user will send something like './test.txt' to the application. how can I get the full path to the file?

Comment: What do you mean by full path? Do you mean get the absolute path of `./test.txt` ?

Comment: Yes. exactly the absolute path

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) is utilized to read argument(s).

For instance;

- The following example assigns the argument at index `2` to a `filepath` variable.

  ```
  const [ , , filepath ] = process.argv;
  ```
- The following example assigns all arguments from index `2` to the `args` variable as an Array.

  ```
  const [ , , ...args ] = process.argv;
  ```

**Note:** Arguments read by `process.argv` at index `0` and `1` are typically the node.js executable path and the JS filepath respectively - hence why in the aforementioned examples we skip over them when [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) the Array, using `, ,`.

---

#### Edit:

Based on the OP's subsequent comment:

> *"How can I get the full path of that file? the user will send something like `./test.txt` to the application. How can I get the [absolute] path to the file?"*

Firstly, the following assumes you are building a command line tool using node.js - as that is what your question implies. In which case consider utilizing [`path.resolve()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths) and pass in [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) and the `filepath` variable.

For instance:

**cli.js**

```js
#! /usr/bin/env node

const { resolve } = require('path');

// 1. Obtain the relative path argument provided via
//    the CLI and assign it to the `filepath` variable.
const [ , , filepath ] = process.argv;

// 2. Obtain the absolute path for the given relative
//    path and assign it to the `absPath` variable.
const absPath = resolve(process.cwd(), filepath);
```

Then in the *package.json* for your global node package you must ensure you've defined your [`bin`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) property something like this:

**package.json**

```json
{
  ...
  "bin": {
    "my-package": "./cli.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

<sub>See [npm blog](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/118810260230/building-a-simple-command-line-tool-with-npm) for further details.</sub>